# Getting the real user who printed a document to an IPP printer

Tags: c, windows, winapi, printing, ipp-protocol

Currently, I'm trying to programmatically **get the name of the user that *started* a printing job** to a mapped [IPP printer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Printing_Protocol).

I'm struggeling with the fact that the [`JOB_INFO_2` structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/job-info-2)'s member `pUserName` contains the name of the user that is being used to connect to the IPP printer and *not* the user that started the print job locally.

To illustrate:

[image]

Looking at both, the [Microsoft's PrintMon tool](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/196805/en-us) and the printer queue they both show the same:

[image]

and

[image]

They show "uwe_keim" as the user that is the owner, although another user started the print job.

This seems to come from the connecting credentials of the user that is being used to authenticate with the IPP printer:

[image]

I'm really clueless on how/whether there is a chance to get the actual user that started a print job (I need this for an app that runs in a multi-user terminal environment).

**So to summarize my question:**

How to get the name of the user who *started* a print job? (in contrast to the name of the user who *owns* a print job)

Comment: To the voters to close: In my opinion this is a programming question, although the screenshots are from end-user applications. I want to know the functions/methods to call to get the user.

Comment: Just be clear that whoever is on the other end has *complete control* over that machine, ouside of your view. They could be lying through their teeth about who is doing the printing.

Comment: I assume all users have the same printer setup using a generic print-server account for the same printer. It looks like the PrintMon can only access ipp authentication data. So I guess your setup should be changed. Each user should authenticate separately at the level of the ipp print server. Then you should get different usernames.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the field `pNotifyName`.

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried this. Unfortunately this value is always `NULL` in my scenario.